# How to import "Route, Router and Switch" correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

It's been an hour now and I can't figure out how to import `Router`, `Route` and `Switch` even after reading countless pages.

My `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import './NavImages.css'


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My `app.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import Settings from './Settings';
import Info from './Info'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Switch } from "react-router";
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
            <Route exact path="/info" component={Info}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Doing this, I get

> You cannot render a  inside another . You never need more than one.
> Even though I dont.

So I tried importing it in a different way.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
```

And I get the error

> Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
> I've tried many more, but it's not worth posting here. Also if it matters, here is my versions.

```
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

How do I import all three of these things without an error?

Comment: I would uninstall both packages and start again with just `react-router-dom` - it will automatically bring in the modules it needs from the base library, you do not need to manually install both. After that, `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
` is the correct syntax. There's not much more to add here. Also having two `Router` components is going to cause bugs, you only need one.

Comment: Ok 2 things. Would the two packages to be `react-router-dom` and `react-router`. And would it be best to remove the `BrowserRouter` in my index.js file or remove the `Router` in my `app.js`?

Comment: Yes, and it's up to you. I usually put mine in `index.js` but so long as it is above all the `Switch` and `Route` components it does not matter.

Comment: The `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';` is 100% valid and what you should be importing. I suspect, as @lawrence-witt points out, there is an issue with the installed node modules, and reinstalling them should in all likelihood resolve the import issue. Since `react-router-dom` re-exports most of `react-router` you should almost never need to import anything from `react-router`.

Comment: Yeah, I realized my whole project package.json node_modules and package_loc.json where somewhat f'd up and not reversible. Creating a new project and moving my files there. I'm now using `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';` and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `<BrowserRouter>` around your `<App>` inside your index.js (like in your case) you can just use the `<Switch>` directly in child components.

Make sure you `import` the components correctly (`Route` from `react-router` and `Switch` from `react-router-dom`).

```js
// imports
import { Route } from "react-router";
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// render
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
  <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
  <Route exact path="/info" component={Info}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Why import from the two packages? In many cases `react-router-dom` is simply re-exporting from `react-router`. It's completely unnecessary to do this, `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'` is perfectly valid. IMO this answer is inaccurate.